# ACCA Python-practical-automation

Tags: python, selenium

Currently doing an exercise for Python automation course where need to open github, find the link and download the file, part of the code for this below:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("header-search-input")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("acca-edx/python-practical-automation")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
```

This part works fine, but when it comes to actually clicking on the results and downloading the file, it gives me an error.
Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("mt-n1").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='fraud-detection.xlsx']").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('raw-url').click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@title='fraud-detection.xlsx']"}
```

I am a beginner at Python so would appreciate any help!

Comment: Is this for the Selenium library?  Please add the appropriate tag(s) for the library/libraries you are using.

Comment: Update the question to show us the debugging work you have done so far. The "fraud" text wasn't found in a HTML element. What _was_ in that element?